# Animate transform: translateX percent of svg path is not working

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I am trying to animate svg path object with css animation. My goal is to animate CSS property `transform: translateX(0%)` to `transform: translateX(50%)`. Please check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3hj8vj4/).

**Two things here**:

- Notice, SVG path object width is 2 times larger than parent SVG.
- If you change percentage in CSS to px, animation is running as expected.

Comment: This seems to be working in Chrome 40.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox 35